# What is the usage of the stones monsters drop?

Tags: danmachi

According to the [Wiki page](https://dungeon-ni-deai-o-motomeru.wikia.com/wiki/Items), adventurers can exchange the gems they collect in the dungeon for money.

> Magic stones are crystal-like stones that are dropped by monsters. The
> stones can be exchanged at the Guild for valis (Orario currency).
>
> The bigger the stone, the more valis it is worth.

I was wondering, why does the Guild want these crystals? Do they have a use?

[image: Gem]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [ja.Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AB%E5%87%BA%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%84%E3%82%92%E6%B1%82%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AF%E9%96%93%E9%81%95%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B#.E3.82.A2.E3.82.A4.E3.83.86.E3.83.A0.E9.96.A2.E9.80.A3):

> **魔石**
>
> モンスターの生命力の核にして、冒険者の飯の種。例外なく胸部に存在する。
> モンスターを倒して胸の魔石をえぐり出し（アニメでは倒すと肉体が消失して魔石だけが残る）、ギルドで換金するのが冒険者の主な収入源。
> 魔力が込められており、照明や下水浄化、調理用コンロ、冷蔵庫など、さまざまな道具に用いられる。
> 胸の魔石を直接攻撃して砕いた場合、モンスターは即死する。

> Magic Stones are the core of the monsters' life force, and adventurers' means of living. Without exception, it locates in the monster's chest.
>
> Killing the monsters, gouging the Magic Stones out of their chests (in the anime, the body of the monsters disappear when defeated, leaving their Magic Stones behind), and cashing them in at the guild is **the main source of income of the adventurers**.
>
> Charged with magic, **Magic Stones can be used to create various tools**, such as lighting, sewage purification, cooking stove, refrigerator, etc.
>
> Monsters die an instant death if the Magic Stone in their chest is destroyed by a direct attack.

[DanMachi Wiki](http://dungeon-ni-deai-o-motomeru.wikia.com/wiki/Magic_Stone) has a bit more details regarding the use of Magic Stones:

> ### Uses
>
> - **Magic Stone Lamp:** A handy and flexible use of the Magic Stone is the production of Magic Stone Lamps. These items give off a dim shine that allows one to see underground or in total darkness. It was once considered as the "century's greatest invention."
> - **Ignition Device:** Magic Stones can be used to produce ignition devices.
> - **Freezer:** Magic Stones are used in the production of freezers to preserve food.

Volume 1, Chapter 2 is cited as the source of the information above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they use it to create potions or armors, weapons and/or anything it can be made out of.

Note that both shards and drop items (monster parts) can be used for crafting. Drop items not necessarily lead to magic items.

> In episode 9 entitled "Blacksmith (Welf Crozzo)", Bell meet Welf Crozzo and at the end of this episode, Welf made Bell a weapon crafted from the horn dropped by the Minotaur he had killed on previous episode.
>
>  Since Crozzo is reluctant to craft magic items, the weapon he crafted from the minotaur' horn is not a magical item.

Additionally, from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_It_Wrong_to_Try_to_Pick_Up_Girls_in_a_Dungeon%3F)

> Adventurers visit the dungeon to defeat monsters and take their shards, which are used to craft magic items.

Comment: I am pretty sure it wasn't the shard that dropped but the Minotaur's horn.

Comment: Did you see that when the horn drops, the outer layer of it, together with the rest of the Minotaur disappears? Take note of that. And on episode 9 with Welf, Bell said that it is just too precious for him to let go or to sold it.

Comment: but even if you say all that, it still is a minotaur horn and not a crystal like the one in the question,
also what bell means by it being too precious to him is that it has sentimental value for him as he was almost killed by a minotaur in one of the previous episodes, so he thought of it as something that proved he overcame his previous weakness and fear.

Comment: yeah of course that's what im talking about the  "precious" term NOT the value for its exchange. Anyway if you say so then why do u think the horn does not disappeared? Do you have any explanation? And did you see if there is anything that drops after the body disappeared? And haven't you noticed that it is still the appearance and color of the shard that JUST LOOK like a horn because of the shape.

Comment: yes but Algaros is asking about the use of the crystals and the Minotaur horn is not one of those crystals, the sword was crafted with only the Minotaur horn as a ingredient so it has nothing to do with the crystals.
he asks about the purpose of the crystals not the horn.

Comment: @Jordy Kramer As i have stated up there it is clear that Im saying that the shards are for crafting potions and creating armors or weapons. So wether that thing that drops from the minotaur is actually a shard or just a horn it's not matter here and that's another issue. It was just an example. But the answer still served the question about the usage of the shard.

Comment: Crozzo calls the horn a "Drop item". In ep 2 it is shown that monsters can drop shards or items. Shards are appraised on their size/purity, not the monster they are from. The minotaur horn is not a shard, since it is still regarded as part of the monster defeated.

Comment: @Mindwin, hmm therefore could it be the horn that served as an item since it is not a shard? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, they mainly act as power sources like batteries. Bigger ones are worth more because they can be used for longer and contain more power.

For example, when watching an episode, look at the lamps. There isn't a candle in there, it is a magic stone.